# Expect script for interacting with a python command line application

Tags: python, expect

Given an interactive python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

name = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
age = raw_input("Please enter your age: ")
print("Happy %s.th birthday %s!" % (age, name))

while 1:
    r = raw_input("q for quit: ")
    if r == "q":
        sys.exit()
```

I want to interact with it from an expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 3
puts "example to interact"
spawn python app.py

expect {
    "name: " { send "jani\r"; }
    "age: "  { send "12\r"; }
    "quit: " { send "q\r"; }
}

puts "bye"
```

The expect script seems to be not interacting with the python appliction just run over that.

Is the problem with the python or with the expect code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is 3 different expect calls:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 3
puts "example to interact"
spawn python app.py

expect "name: " { send "jani\r" }
expect "age: " { send "12\r" }
expect "quit: " { send "q\r" }
```

The reason is the `expect` command does not work like a loop. Once it handles the input/output, it moves on.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need expect?

```
python app.py <<END_INPUT
jani
12
q
END_INPUT
```

Comment: My real problem is about an ssh session, where the login include a lot of extra lines, that also has got machine specific information. I have to run some 'yum remove cvs' in some condition on 90 servers. It is only my learning curve on Expect.

Comment: That requirement has nothing to do with your question. Did you research [tag:expect] questions about automating ssh? There must be dozens of similar questions already.